# How to start with React JS to build chart components

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React JS visioned to build chart components. I have read about WebPack, core libraries and npm. Can I have some help on pre-requisites, IDE and guidance to write basic components?

Comment: are you planning to build the chart components on your own, or by making use of some existing libraries?

Comment: I would like to build on my own. But you can also share information on existing library as well.

Comment: To get you started, I'd recommend taking a look at plottable](http://plottablejs.org/components/)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWu I can see attractive components. Does plottablejs use React JS library? or it is an alternate to React?

Comment: It does not since it's a lower level library that you can use to wrap your own charting components around. Blueprintjs is working on open sourcing a [charting library](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/235) that will be providing things as react components though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to start learning reacjs, please follow the getting started guide for it on React homepage. It is quite easy to follow.
- Webpack, just a bundling tool, and provide you many plugins for your react code (transpiler, liting, bundling ...)
- NPM is an dependencies management tool (if you come from Java world, you can count it as Maven, it do some same things on dependencies)
- IDE, You can start with just simple text editor like Sublime Text, notepad ++ or anything you want.
- About the chart library, D3 is highly recommended for all client framework: https://github.com/d3/d3

Answer (score 0):

IDE I use my friend is atom with this plugins :

1. linter
2. ternjs,
3. language-babel ,
4. autocomplete modules ,
5. css-in-js,dockblockr ,
6. file-icons ,
7. highlight-selected,prettier-atom ,
8. atom-beautify
9. ,linter-eslint

   You need to learn es6 a very useful way to program

read about react patterns https://reactpatterns.com/

learn redux and redux-thunk for asynchrony maybe it is hard to start but it is very useful for bigger apps

for charts I usually use antd or react-charts https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-charts

and if you downloaded a template you will find many other